# Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b returns empty on example code

Tags: salesforce, large-language-model

I am running the exact example code for `Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b` from here: https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/blip2-opt-2.7b

But I consistently get `</s>\n`, no matter if I use CPU or GPU. I see some activity in the target device, but the answer is always the same.
I also tried with a local image and different prompts, no difference.
Anyone had a similar situation?